# Исправить в 1С ошибку сокращенной конструкции

Tags: 1с

В 1С есть такая сокращенная конструкция:

```
&НаКлиенте 
Процедура Команда1(Команда) ?(1>2,"Вот это правильно!!!", "Не то!!!"); 
КонецПроцедуры
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Встроенная функция может быть использована только в выражении
```

Как его исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тернарная условная операция "**?()**" возвращает значение.
[image: Справка из синтакс-помощника]

Программа у вас ругается, что результат функции "некуда положить". Попробуйте так:

```
Результат = ?(1>2,"Вот это правильно!!!", "Не то!!!");
```